# Show that for any real number c, it is possible to rearrange the terms of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} (1/n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that for any real number c, it is possible to rearrange the terms of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} (1/n)$ so that the sum is exactly c.

Comment: This is true more generally, it's in fact true for any series that converges conditionally.

Comment: See here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSeriesTheorem.html

Comment: Reimann Rearrangement theorem

Comment: The obvious places that you did not even check accumulate... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem#Examples

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/46195

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Series rearrangement and Riemann's theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46195/series-rearrangement-and-riemanns-theorem)

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

Suppose $c>0$. Add the positive terms of the series, one by one, i.e. do the addition $1+1/3+1/5+...$ and stop till this rises above $c$.

Then, start adding the negative terms i.e. $-1/2-1/4-1/6-...$ to the above so that the result just drops below $c$.

Repeat this step with the remaining positive and negative terms.