# How to rearrange alternating harmonic series to get sum of 1

Tags: summation

How can we rearrange $$ \sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n} $$ to get the sum 1
I know we know the alternation of sum by$$\frac{1}{2}\log{k}$$
Edit:sorry forgot to include $$k=a/b $$
a is number of positive terms taken

b is number of negative terms taken

If we use above formula
$$ 1=\log(2)+(1/2)\log(k)$$
We get $k=e^2/4$
I am not sure what taking e^2 terms mean

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. What is $k$? What do you mean by "rearrange to get sum $1$"?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Riemann rearrangement theorem?  Do you know the proof?  The proof I know is rather constructive...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Series rearrangement and Riemann's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46195/series-rearrangement-and-riemanns-theorem)

Comment: Pick a sequence $a_n/b_n$ that tends to $e^2/4$. Put, in the natural order, $a_n$ positive terms, then $b_n$ negative terms, and so on.

Comment: "I know we know the alternation of sim by $\frac12{\log k}$." What does that mean?

Comment: @DanielGeyfman k is ratio of positive and negative terms taken sequentially,I have edited the question please check

Comment: @ThomasAndrews k is ratio of positive and negative terms taken sequentially,I have edited the question please check

Comment: "I know we get the alternation of sums" is the meaningless part. Why do you assume $1=\log 2 +\frac12\log k?$

Comment: If you mean $a_n,b_n$ is the number of positive and negative terms in the $n$th partial sum, and $k$ is the limit of $a_n/b_n,$ then it isn't even clear that the limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get any desired sum $S$:

- Add up enough odd terms until the first time you exceed $S$
- Subtract enough even terms until you go below $S$
- Add more odd terms until you exceed $S$ again
- Subtract more even terms until you go below $S$ again

If you want $S =1$ specifically, here's what that looks like:

- $1 + \frac{1}{3} > 1$
- $1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} < 1$
- $1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} > 1$
- $1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{4} < 1,$

and so on forever.

Comment: Does it follow any certain pattern for terms?

Comment: A pattern could be constructed based on the algorithm given above, but it would most likely be somewhat messy and unintuitive. Additionally, this rearrangement is not unique; there are many different ways to change the order of the positive and negative terms to get a sum of $S = 1$ (or any other desired sum).